# multiple object querydict to lists

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am sending some javascript objects as array of objects to django view via ajax. The object is like:

```
[{'oid':'id1','oiid':'iid1'},{'oid':'id2','oiid':'iid2'}]
```

My ajax:

```
....
type : "POST",
data : {action:'pack_orders',
        order_dict:$checkedRows},
....
```

I can see the request in django view as QueryDict like:

```
<QueryDict : {'order_dict[0][oid]':'id1','order_dict[0][oiid]':'iid1',
              'order_dict[1][oid]':'id2','order_dict[1][oiid]':'iid2'}>
```

How can i get lists from querydict in django view like:

```
oid_list = ['id1','id2']
oiid_list = ['iid1','iid2']
```

Output in views.py:

```
{'order_dict[0][oid]':'id1','order_dict[0][oiid]':'iid1',
 'order_dict[1][oid]':'id2','order_dict[1][oiid]':'iid2'}
```

EDIT:

1) Added views.py output from statement `print dict(request.POST)`

Comment: Have you tried printing `order_dict` in your views? What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are sending `order_dict` after JSON.stringifying it. If not, I suggest do it. Accept it as json string in your view, do a json.loads() on it. Post this you have a list of dictionary.

Lets say you store it in variable called data, then you can do as following

```
oid_list = [x.get('oid') for x in data]
oiid_list = [x.get('oiid') for x in data]
```

**Output:**

```
oid_list - ['id1', 'id2']
oiid_list - ['iid1', 'iid2']
```

Should work for you. I dont know if its the best solution, but a simple one.